# File opencv_cudaoptflow340.lib missing

Tags: opencv, cmake, lib

I have compiled **opencv3.4.0** with **cuda9.1** support using CMake on Windows 10:

[image]

and then I built the **INSTALL** file in **visual studio 2015** in **OpenCV.sln**.

But this is my Release folder:

[image]

The file **opencv_cudaoptflow340.lib** is not anywhere in C drive, however it should be in **C:\opencv_3.4.0\opencv\build\lib\Release**. How can I build opencv so that these library and dll files are generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build opencv_worldxxx.lib all is inside as well in opencv_worldxxx.dll. You can unmark the option in Cmake related to opencv_world library. Than the libs and dll will be in separate files. Marked world all is in that single file. Unmarked option generates opencv_core opencv_videoio opencv_ml .lib .dll. You can decide one or another. There is difference in link one library or several libraries and consider this in packaging of your app. [build in Cmake](https://funvision.blogspot.com/2018/11/build-opencv-34-under-windows-10-with.html?m=1)